# Conservation of Critical Points Under Strictly Monotone Function Composition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose we have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is differentiable on some interval $I$. Let's say $\exists c \in I: f'(c) = 0$.

If we have a strictly monotone function $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $U$ is some open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $f(c)$, why does $(g$ ∘ $f)'(c) = 0?$

I have tried reasoning this using the limit definition of the derivative, and applying definitions for monotonicity, but can't seem to reach a conclusion.

Comment: Why does $U$ need to contain $c$? Is that supposed to say $U\ni f(c)$?

Comment: Is that g(f(x)) or g(x)×f(x) ????

Comment: @Raiyan Chowdhury Beware that in order to be able to legitimately speak about the composition $g \circ f$ you must require the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ of $f$ to coincide with the definition domain $U$ of $g$, so $U$ can't be just ''some open subset''. Either that or you are thinking about the composition between $g$ and a suitable restriction of $f$, whose codomain would be $U$. At any rate, without precise ammendments, the notation $g \circ f$ is illicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivative rule for compound functions: $(g\circ f)'(c)=g'(f(c))\cdot f'(c)$.